# I accidentally deleted the file /lib/ld-lsb.so.3

Tags: release-juno, apt, shared-libraries

I accidentally deleted the file /lib/ld-lsb.so.3. I wanted to know if it's a necessary file to guarantee the good functionality of the system (last version of Elementary OS, equivalent to bionic Ubuntu), and in case how to restore it. I gave a look to this post (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035916/how-do-i-restore-libz-so-1) to see if I can find and restore the deleted file, but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance for your help.